# Arduino SoftwareSerial - can't get data from NEO 6M-GPS module

Tags: gps, tinygps

I am using Mikael Hart's TinyGPS (v.13) library and example code to talk to my module. The LED on the GPS module is lit and flashing which I assume means it is receiving data from the GPS satellites. The module seller claims that the module has a default baud of 38400.

I'm pretty sure it's wired up correctly:

[image: Arduino side]
[image: Neo 6M-0-001 side]

And my sketch says:

```
SoftwareSerial ss(4, 3);
```

So I read this as Orange (Rx) to pin 4 and Brown (Tx) to pin 3.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RX of the Arduino (pin 4, according to the SoftwareSerial statement) goes to the TX of the GPS.  Arduino pin 3 (ss TX) goes to the GPS RX.

And you should use pins 8 & 9 instead.  That would let you use [AltSoftSerial](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/AltSoftSerial), the best choice when you can't use HardwareSerial (i.e., `Serial`).

If you can't use pins 8 & 9, then [NeoSWSerial](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoSWSerial) is a better choice than SoftwareSerial.

And while I'm promoting NeoSWSerial, I'll mention a library I wrote, [NeoGPS](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS)...  It's faster and smaller than all other GPS libraries, and very configurable.  It also has several [diagnostic programs](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS/blob/master/doc/Examples.md#diagnostics) and a [Troubleshooting](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS/blob/master/doc/Troubleshooting.md) section in the docs.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give it ago and report back. Your answer came a little after I'd put everything away for the day. . The chip specif library in particular sounds very useful.